# PowerBI DAX measure to calculate duration of assignment based on just one date field (Assign date). End date is when value stops appearing

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have trouble putting together the logic to solve the following with DAX measures.

I have a 'Facts table' with three columns: [Assign_Date] in date format, [Person ID] text and [Assignement ID] text. None of the values is unique and theres a relationship between [Assign_Date] and Calendar[Date].

eg.

| Assign_Date | Person ID | Assignement ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09 September 2023 | Person A | XY1 |
| 09 September 2023 | Person B | XY55 |
| 16 September 2023 | Person B | XY55 |
| 23 September 2023 | Person B | XY1 |
| 23 September 2023 | Person C | XY89 |
| 30 September 2023 | Person D | XY1 |
| 30 September 2023 | Person D | XY89 |

Assign_date is a fixed date each week. (eg. Every saturday the last 5 years). People do concecutive dates and we don't need to consider a scenario where they re-appear after some time. Each Person ID starts an Assignement ID on the earliest [Assign_date] they appear on the table. There are no end dates. They remain assigned, and their last day is assumed the date when there is no longer a record of their User ID. Eg. Last date for person B is 30 September (duration 3 weeks). In a more granular level, Last date for person B in Assignement XY55 is 23 september (duration 2 weeks). The only order that matters for assignements is date order.

a) It is most important for me to calculate the interval in days (or weeks) between the earliest date a User ID appeared on the table and the date it stopped appearing. No Assignement detail needed for this calculation.

b) I'd like a list which user IDs completed all their assignements each month of the year. Assuming something to do with CONCATINATEX.

c) Nice to have the interval in days (or weeks) where a User ID remained assigned to a specific Assignement ID.

I have tried playing with DATEDIFF, SUMX, EARLIER AND CONCATINATEX but quite early in my DAX journey and I've not been able to create the right syntax to solve this

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If UserA is in week 1 then not in week 2, their end date would be the start of week 2? And the same user now reappears in week 5 and not longer appears in week 7 - would this mean they were assigned a different task? Surely Assignment ID is relevant, no?

Comment: Hi, they do concecutive dates, and re-occurence after some time is rare but not impossible. Maybe one or two cases per year. Would be good to know eventually but would  rather nail the basics first. We consider the end date of their full assignment (independent of ID/task) to be the first date when their user ID no longer appears. There is one scenario of the problem (c) where it'd be nice to have the Assignment ID length . In that case  the end date would be the first date when an Assignement ID and User ID no longer appeared.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide a sample table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) with a few rows showing a user assigned and then not assigned.

Comment: thanks, i updated and hopefully now more clear

Comment: Perfect, lastly, what would be the end date for Person A, Person B, and Person C? Assuming Person D not finished yet.

Comment: it'd be the first instance when they no longer appear, So , person A  last day is 16 September 2023, person B 30 September 2023, person C 30 September 2023. Person D undetermined

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in PowerQuery to simplify your `Facts table`.

```
let
  Source = YOUR_SOURCE,
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Assign_Date", type date}, {"Person ID", type text}, {"Assignement ID", type text}}),
  dateList = List.Distinct(#"Changed column type"[Assign_Date]),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed column type", {"Person ID", "Assignement ID"}, {{"Date Assigned", each List.Min([Assign_Date]), type nullable date}, {"Last Date", each List.Max([Assign_Date]), type nullable date}}),
  #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped rows", "Date Completed", each 
    let
      thisD = [Last Date],
      res = List.First(List.Select(dateList, each _ > thisD))
    in
      res
  , type date),
  #"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added custom", {"Last Date"})
in
  #"Removed columns"
```

This will give you a table where there is only one row per Person per Assignment:

| Person ID | Assignement ID | Date Assigned | Date Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | XY1 | 9/9/2023 | 9/16/2023 |
| Person B | XY55 | 9/9/2023 | 9/23/2023 |
| Person B | XY1 | 9/23/2023 | 9/30/2023 |
| Person C | XY89 | 9/23/2023 | 9/30/2023 |
| Person D | XY1 | 9/30/2023 | null |
| Person D | XY89 | 9/30/2023 | null |

Load the query into your data model, and I suggest **not** having a relationship between this table and your `Calendar` table. The following assumes there isn't a relationship between them.

---

Create a Measure for (a):

```
Assigned duration - days = 
  var result =
    SUMX(
      DISTINCT('Facts table'[Person ID]),
      DATEDIFF(
        MIN('Facts table'[Date Assigned]),
        COALESCE(MAX('Facts table'[Date Completed]), TODAY()),
        DAY
      )
    )

  return result
```

[image]

---

Create a Measure for (b):

```
Users completed = 
  var filteredDateMin = MIN(Calendar[Date])
  var filteredDateMax = MAX(Calendar[Date])

  var result =
    CALCULATE(
      CONCATENATEX(
        DISTINCT('Facts table'[Person ID]),
        [Person ID],
        ", "
      ),
      filteredDateMin <= 'Facts table'[Date Completed] &&
      'Facts table'[Date Completed] <= filteredDateMax &&
      NOT ISBLANK('Facts table'[Date Completed])
    )

  return result
```

[image]

---

Create a Measure for (c):

```
Assigned duration - not completed - days = 
  CALCULATE(
    [Assigned duration - days],
    FILTER('Facts table', [Date Completed] = BLANK() )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very Much Sam. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I'd still be interested to see if there is a version of this solved only by DAX to avoid potential increase in loading time.

Comment: Equivalent can be done in DAX too, but I would recommend doing it in PowerQuery which will result in a smaller sized data model (all those surplus rows per week per person per assignment are squished into one). Doing it in DAX will add complexity and may reduce performance.